# Python: decorating a list of objects

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently studying Python and I wrote this code to explore the decorator's mechanism.

Suppose I have a list of objects and a function that I want to use to decorate one of their methods, but I don't want the decoration to be permanent.

This is one way to achieve that result:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Man(Human):
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello, my name is " + self.name)

    def __call__(self):
        self.hello()

class Woman(Human):
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello, my name is " + self.name)

    def __call__(self):
        self.hello()

def deco(func):
    def wrap():
        print("-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-")
        func()
        print("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
    return wrap

H = Man("Harry")
S = Woman("Sally")

print("\n")

H.hello()
S.hello()

print("\n\nDecoration:\n")

people = [H, S]

for f in list(map(deco, people)):
    f()

print("\n")
```

this is the output:

```
Hello, my name is Harry
Hello, my name is Sally


Decoration:

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
Hello, my name is Harry
*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
Hello, my name is Sally
*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

which is the desired output.

Another way to obtain it could be to remove the **call** definition in the classes and use this:

```
functions = [H.hello, S.hello]

for f in list(map(deco, functions)):
    f()
```

which I would prefer, because I'm explicitly passing the function that I want to be decorated to the deco() decorator.

I'm not satisfied though, because I'm looking for a thing like this

```
people = [H, S]

for i in range(len(people)):
    decoratedHello = deco(people[i].hello)
    decoratedHello()
```

but this one looks more like a C++ style of thinking, and I'm looking for a way to achieve this in a more Python fashioned style. Anybody knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call this decorating, given you are doing it on an instance basis, this is just more a functional closure and largely unnecessary because you could just call the function directly. Why not create a decorated method on the class rather than the instance?

Comment: "Why not create a decorated method on the class rather than the instance?" There is no reason. This is not a work project, I'm just studying Python and exploring the opportunities it offers :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this

```
for f in (deco(p.hello) for p in people):
    f()
```

Or this

```
for p in people:
    decorated = dec(p.hello)
    decorated()
```

But IMHO, the most **pythonic** one is: #like your first try...

```
for f in map(deco, people):
    f()
```

Comment: I really like your first solution. Thanks a lot.